# How to replace all lines of a file with their substring with Ant?

Tags: ant, substring

E.g. to trim the first *n* characters of the lines, so that

```
123
1234
```

becomes

```
3
34
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<target name="test">
        <property name="trim_count" value="2"/>
        <copy file="c:/test.txt" tofile="c:/test2.txt" overwrite="true">
                <filterchain>
                        <tokenfilter>
                        <linetokenizer/>
                        <replaceregex pattern="^.{1,${trim_count}}(.*)" replace="\1"/>
                        </tokenfilter>
                        <ignoreblank/>
                </filterchain>
        </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought of replaceregexp (not replaceregex!) but couldn't come up with a solution because I was thinking along the lines of specifying the substring length with a number. This solution doesn't scale well with the length of the trimmed substring, but it is simple, and anyway, this length will be 6 in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, great! I had to remove the <stringtokenizer/> filter, though, or replace it with <linetokenizer/>.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I think that <linetokenizer/> is more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a java class to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ant supports this type of functionality by default. Instead you'd have to use an external utility. If you share some specifics of the OS you are using, as well as what kind of characters or pattern that you are attempting to remove we might be able to further aid you.